# Arduino Wire Types?

Tags: arduino-nano, wires

I don't know what wires to get for my first Arduino project. I am planning on getting a pre-made light strip that I would control with an Arduino from across my room. Is there any specific type of wire to get? It needs to be about 15 feet. There are so many choices, but I don't know what I need. Does anyone else know?

Comment: What light strip? How long do you want the wire to be? What are your needs? Do you have an unusually hot/cold room? (Kidding with the last question :D)

Answer (score 4):

Choosing wire all depends on what you're going to do with it, and most of the choice is based on how much current it will carry and how durable it needs to be. Generally, you're going to use insulated copper wire - aside from that, your answers are mostly here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16948/choosing-the-right-type-of-wire

For experimentation - which you will need to do a lot of before attempting your goal project - you can use the little wires which come in the Arduino starter kit. They are "jumper wires" designed for use on a bread board - they can not carry large amounts of electricity.

This product here: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8431 - these have "male" ends designed to be stuck into the holes in the breadboard, and connect to the holes on the headers of the Arduino.

Here's an example of a project laid out on a breadboard:
[image: Compass Project]

None of those wires carry a lot of current. If you're hooking up 50 LEDs that might be almost a full 1-AMP of current, so I would use thicker wire. Do yourself a favor and start with a kit like in this video, learn the basics, then attempt a 'real' project. Every Arduino user should be able to do all the experiments in the training book and understand them. You will be lost if you jump in deep right away...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pf4qosqpv3A

Comment: While you can indeed use these stranded wires with solid ends, they may tend to break at the junction.  Plain 22 gauge solid wire works too, and is cheaper.  High power loads should not be drawing their power *through* the arduino board anyway.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yes that's very important. It's covered in the video how to do that. Shows how to run the lights and the Arduino on two different power sources.